# REST PUT request returning a GET 500 error, is that plausible?

Tags: php, rest, angularjs

I am not any kind of RESTful API expert, but I have a simple `PUT/DELETE` function in an AngularJS app that has been functioning as expected until now. I am trying to work out whether this problem is likely to lie in my app, or in the (php) back-end that is running the endpoint. Other REST services are functioning normally & the server appears to be running fine.

This function only ever calls PUT or DELETE, assigned as `var method`:

```
     if (food.favourite === true) {
                method = "PUT";
                console.log("method is " + method)

            } else if (food.favourite === false) {
                method = "DELETE";
                console.log("method is " + method)
            }
            $http({
                method: method,
                url: $scope.URL
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(method + " successful")
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(method + " not successful")
            });
```

I have one `$http GET` in my app that uses a different endpoint.  There is no `$http GET` pointing to this endpoint anywhere in my app- I have searched extensively.

When I trigger the function containing the $http above, the console shows:

```
 method is PUT 
 GET http://localhost:8888/api/ext/51/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
 PUT not successful
```

Why would I be receiving a `GET` error on an unsuccessful PUT request? Does this point to a problem in my function, or a problem with the endpoint?

Thank you for any help in understanding this problem.

---

Update 1

Info from the Network panel: calling the $http function above triggers two simultaneous requests, one 'PUT' and one 'GET'. The 'PUT' returns a 301 code, and the 'GET' returns a 500 server error (which I think is to be expected, as this endpoint is not set up to respond to 'GET', only to 'PUT' and 'DELETE').

So: why would my code be generating two simultaneous requests with different methods?

Comment: Well, i dont know AngularJS but i would like to highlight here that default is `GET` method. So, check if due to some reason, is default method is called though `method` has `PUT`

Comment: I've checked the Network panel these calls, and it looks like 2 simultaneous actions are called: a PUT & a GET, for the same endpoint. The continues if I change the code above to manually assign method: 'PUT'.

Comment: `PUT` shouldn't return 301 under normal conditions. 301 is telling the client to redirect to the URL that the server provides in the `Location` header. But it sounds like the client is not following RFC 2616 in this regard: "If the 301 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued."

Answer (score 0):

For future seekers of answers to similar questions: it is a standard behaviour (of REST in general or this implentation? Not sure) to try to return a GET for every action that is called. Evidence for this is that if I check the Network panel for all the other (successful) $http functions, they also have two actions visible: the original PUT/GET/DELETE etc, + a GET.

We are seeing a 500 Error on the GET for these particular requests because the configuration of this particular endpoint does not allow for a GET. This should not have any effect on the PUT/DELETE actions on this endpoint- the 500 Error is not related to the reason why the PUT/DELETE actions weren't working. In terms of trying to solve this specific problem, it's a red herring.

The reason the PUT/DELETE was not working was because the service was broken on the server-side.

Comment: That's certainly not standard for REST systems implemented with HTTP. First of all, the server cannot return a `GET`; it can only return a URL in the Location header and a status code in the 300 family to indicate that the resource is actually located somewhere else. Secondly, it sounds not only like the service was broken but also that your client mishandled a 301. It's also possible that your client is issuing a GET after what it perceives to be a successful PUT in case the service calculated or changed some values of the resource that the client wants to know about.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and the issue was in how I was outputting the errors in the first argument for `header`. They need to be in this format:

```
header('400: Error', true, 400);
```

or in your case, of course:

```
header('301: Moved Permanently', true, 301);
header('Location: ' . $url);
```

Note that this WILL NOT work:

```
header('Some Random Text', true, 400); // $http.error shows status of 500
```